# How am I supposed to use brackets in HTML to check the authentification?

Tags: html, django

I want to use `{% is.user_authentificated %}` to change a function display, but when I add this line, it shows it in the view when I reload the page. Did I do something wrong in it ?

```
    {% if is.user_authentificated %}
        li><a ng-if="item.detail_url.indexOf('/layers/') > -1" href="{% 
        endverbatim %}{% url "new_map" %}?layer={% verbatim %}{{ 
        item.detail_url.substring(8) }}">
        {% endverbatim %}
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>{% trans "Create a Map" %}</a>
        {% verbatim %}
         </li>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: I think the tag you're looking for is `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

Comment: oh yes my bad I miswrote the if statement, thanks but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the issue. I was placing my tag in a verbatim tag. So I moved it after the `{% endverbatim %}`and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    // if user is authenticated then write your code here 
{% endif  %}
```